# Warning given and i can not understand why after about 10 minutes of research so i am asking

Tags: c, putty

I get a warning that says left hand comma operand has no effect so i looked at some other examples oon here and dont understand what causes it.

```
FILE * input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if(strcmp(argv[1],"-r") != 0 && strcmp(argv[1],"-u") != 0 && strcmp(argv[1],"-l") != 0)
    {
      return("Option %c is not supported",'k');
    }
```

Why does this give me that error and how would I go about fixing it?

the exact error is  "warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect" on the line of the if statment

Comment: What do you hope that that `return` statement would do?

Comment: I gave you a downvote for not quoting the EXACT warning message and indicating which line of your code was flagged.

Comment: You are going to post problems here every time you get stuck for 10 minutes?

Comment: Your function return a `FILE`... where is it?

Comment: i was returning the name of the command not supported but switched it to k trying to figure out what part was wrong. what i want it to do for example would be print to the screen "Option -cow is not supported" but if it is -r,-u,-l then it just passes this doing nothing

Comment: Please spend at least 20 minutes to read a C book

Comment: maybe you can print message and then `exit(-1)`

Comment: ^^ what @HotLicks says.  Learn how to report bugs befroe posting here again.  Also, learning some C may help.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do I got stuck so I asked a question thought you would be more helpful and less rude.

Comment: Well, SO is a Q&A site for prfessional and enthusiast programmers.  Some might say that asking for a C tutorial is rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
return("Option %c is not supported",'k');
```

is the same as

```
return('k');
```

since the expression `"Option %c is not supported"` has no side effect.

Given that the return type of the function is `FILE*`,

```
return('k');
```

is a problem since `'k'` is not of type `FILE*`.

It seems you are not sure what you are doing. Perhaps a [good tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm) will be useful.